# netcat command in c++

Tags: c++, qt, netcat

I am a newbee when it comes to coding in C++.
I am currently using qt to make a simple GUI, where I want to send a command to a device via TCP/IP.

When i connect my computer to the device and via the terminal send the command:

```
echo '3b00010000001b010001000000120000013000002713000300030101' | xxd -r -p | nc 192.168.1.101 30013
```

The device does correspondently.

I need to be able to send this command in qt as a function. Can anyone help me? This is what i have so far (does not work)

Header:

```
#ifndef SOCKET_H
#define SOCKET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Socket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Socket(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void Connect(const QString &host, const string &cmd);

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
};

#endif // SOCKET_H
```

Cpp:

```
#include "socket.h"

Socket::Socket(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void Socket::Connect(const QString &host, const string &cmd)
{
    //connect
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost(host,30013);

    if(socket->waitForConnected(1500))
    {
        qDebug() << "Connected";

        //send
        socket->write(cmd.c_str(), cmd.size());
        socket->waitForBytesWritten(1000);

        //close
        socket->close();
    }

    else
        qDebug() << "Not Connected";

}
```

Then I want to send the command by:

```
Socket.Test
Test.Connect("192.168.1.101","3b00010000001b010001000000120000013000002713000300030101")
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: presumably you need to convert your command from hex to binary? You also have your command and host the wrong way round when you call `Connect`

Comment: Sorry about that, was a typo from my side. I have tried it the correct way around. Have corrected my post. How do i convert from hex to binary in c++? is there a function i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your command is a fixed string you can simply enter the characters directly:

```
const char data[] = "\x3b\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x01\x30\x00\x00\x27\x13\x00\x03\x00\x03\x01\x01";
Test.Connect("192.168.1.101",string(data, sizeof(data)-1));
```

Note that as your data has embedded null characters you can't simply pass the string literal to `std::string` as it would truncate the string before the first null character.

Comment: Tried it but does not work. Can i be something wrong with the variables in my connect() function?

Comment: @Frodi I can't really help with "does not work" I'm afraid. Have you tried debugging? Have you tried using wireshark to check the network traffic?

Comment: Got it working :)
Was a small problem with the cmd.size parameter. Now it works like a charm.
Thank you :)